# AKS Page not Found for SwaggerUI

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, azure-aks, swashbuckle

I have a `.net core 6 web api` service which I have deployed on AKS(Azure Kubernetes Services). The `Program.cs` looks like so;

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var swaggerConfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SwaggerConfig)).Get<SwaggerConfig>();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opts =>
{
    opts.SchemaFilter<ExampleNashSchemaFilter>();
    opts.SwaggerDoc(swaggerConfig.ApiVersion, new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = swaggerConfig.ApiName, Version = swaggerConfig.ApiVersion });
    
});

builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    // Only loopback proxies are allowed by default.
    // Clear that restriction because forwarders are enabled by explicit 
    // configuration.
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});


builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("devcors", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));


var app = builder.Build();


app.UseCors("devcors");

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v1/swagger.json", swaggerConfig.ApiName);
    c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
});


app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();


app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();


app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

Here is the  swagger settings on `appsettings.json`

```json
 "SwaggerConfig": {
    "ApiName": "Some Services",
    "ApiVersion": "v1"
  }
```

Here is my `deployment.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: servicetest
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: servicetest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: servicetest
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: servicetest
        image: myprivatehub/servicetest:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: servicetest
spec:
  selector:
    app: servicetest
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

For some weird reasons I can access the APIs running from my service on AKS but I can't access the `swagger/index.html` I get an error page can't be found. I replicated this deployment on my minikube and it works well. I'm curious to know why i can't access swaggerUI from AKS

Comment: I was building the wrong image smh...

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you do not have an [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) deployed on your AKS. You will need that in order to get [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to work and to expose the swagger-ui.

To access the swagger-ui for testing purposes you can do this:

```
kubectl port-forward service/servicetest 80:8080
```

Afterwards just access http://localhost:8080

But you should def. install an ingress-controller: Here is a Workflow from MS to install [ingress-nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli) as Ingress Controller on your Cluster.

To avoid that every service spawns a LoadBalancer and a PublicIP in Azure (to keep an eye on your costs), you will then only expose the ingress-controller to the internet and could also specify the loadBalancerIP statically if you created the PublicIP in advance:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: myResourceGroup # only needed if the LB is in another RG
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: <YOUR_STATIC_IP>
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The Ingress Controller then will route incoming traffic to your application with an Ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx # ingress-nginx specifix
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: servicetest
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Hello I have tried this but I am getting Status pending on `ingress-nginx-controller` I have supplied it with the servicetest external ip

Comment: Also should I keep my service loadbalancer

Comment: hi, for testing purpose remove the annotation and the static ip on the service, azure will then create a loadbalancer with a dynamic external IP for you.

Comment: the service is a LoadBalaner?

Comment: yes, it's in the last part of my question

Comment: but you still need ingress to expose something...this is how kubernetes works....or you use kubectl port-forward

Comment: so, should I replace my Loadbalancer with the one you shared?

Comment: the only loadbalancer in the cluster shoulkd be the ingress controller.....the IC is the single entrypoint to your cluster....your testservice should be type ClusterIP

Comment: localtest for `kubectl port-forward` works well but somehow AKS can't seem to find the path `/swagger` are you in a position to replicate this issue using my question as a reference?